# How to test a method dispatching custom event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, jestjs, enzyme

I have a static method that creates a custom event and dispatches it:

```
    class MyComponent extends {
       static refreshComponent() {
         const event = new Event('refreshComponent');
         document.dispatchEvent(event);
       }
       render() {
          MyComponent.refreshComponent();
       }
    }
```

I am trying test as below:

```
describe('refreshComponent', () => {
    it('should dispatch an event', () => {
      const document = { dispatchEvent: jest.fn() };
      wrapper.refreshGoalsComponent();
      expect(document.dispatchEvent).toHaveBeenCalledWith('refreshComponent');
    });
  });
```

But the dispatchEvent is not called here, as there is no mock for 'new Event()'. Is there a way to mock it? Please help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a little clunky looking, but something like this should work if you want to verify an event with the expected `type` was dispatched:

```
describe('refreshComponent', () => {
  it('should dispatch an event', () => {
    const dispatchEventSpy = jest.spyOn(document, 'dispatchEvent');

    // Trigger component render here...

    expect(dispatchEventSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(Event));
    expect(dispatchEventSpy.mock.calls[0][0].type).toBe('refreshComponent');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can test dispatch event like this:

```
describe('refreshComponent', () => {
  it('should dispatch an event', () => {
    jest.spyOn(global, 'Event').mockImplementation((type: string, eventInit?: any) => ({ type, eventInit }));
    const mockDispatchEvent = jest.spyOn(document, 'dispatchEvent').mockImplementation(() => true);

    // render your component

    expect(mockDispatchEvent).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      type: 'refreshComponent',
    });
  });
});
```

This way can expect event type and event init value. If you don't want to expect detail event, we does not need to mock Event and expect like:

```
expect(mockDispatchEvent).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(Event));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can mock globals with Jest:

```js
describe('your test', () => {
  let EventBak
  let documentBak

  beforeAll(() => {
    EventBak = global.Event
    documentBak = global.document
    global.Event = jest.fn()
    global.document = {
      ...global.document,
      dispatchEvent: jest.fn()
    }
  })

  afterAll(() => {
    global.Event = EventBak
    global.document = documentBak
  })

  it('...', () => {
    ...
    expect(global.document.dispatchEvent).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

Comment: Jest now complaining for the dispatchEvent to be mocked:
expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalledWith()

    jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
    Received:
      function: [Function dispatchEvent]

Comment: Do we need JSDOM API to mock document?

Comment: Depends on your jest setup

Comment: If you are using jsdom env, you don't need to mock it: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string

Comment: but you can't check if it has been called then